# Password auto fill issue in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login page with password field.When user saves the password in browser it will auto populate next time.I want to get the value after auto fill.Currently the value is empty when checking it in document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#PasswordField').val() != "")
    {
         //TO DO
    }       
});
```

Comment: Try checking the value from your console using $('#PasswordField').val(). It would be helpful if you can post your html code as well

Comment: which browser are you using? have you tried onChange event?

Comment: @AbdullahDanyal Tried change event.But In intial load only it works.When we just refresh page it won't work

Comment: please comment your browser and its version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the "change" event is only triggered when the element loses focus, so it's not suitable to capture the value of an auto-fill robot. This should work instead:

```
$(document).on("input", "#PasswordField", function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "")
    {
         //TO DO
    }       
});
```

Comment: This will work only on first load.But on next page refresh it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

### Password autofill issue in browsers

After much research i can say that it is totally ***dependent on browser***. Change event works for some browsers and some browsers don't dispatch the change event. There is no exact/same solution for this.

The thing is when browsers pre-fill the username and password fields, as in that case the username and password fields don't gain and loose the focus that's why the change event don't triggered.

The code below work for some browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#password").change(function (argument) {
    console.log($("#password").val());
 });      
});
```

You can also try this inside `$(document).ready()`:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
     console.log($("#password").val());
    },2000);
```

For better understanding about this autofill concept and browser compatibilities please read this [short article](http://avernet.blogspot.fi/2010/11/autocomplete-and-javascript-change.html).